# Nested classes don't see each other

Tags: python-3.x

To be honest, I don't even know how to describe the problem in more detail. I have this code:

```
class DatasetController:
    class DatasetItemStructure(TypedDict):
        files: List[str]
        concatenated: str

    class DatasetInfoStructure(TypedDict):
        base_path: str
        qr_code_samplerate: int
        items: Dict[str, DatasetController.DatasetItemStructure]
```

And I get an error

```
    items: Dict[str, DatasetController.DatasetItemStructure]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'DatasetController' is not defined
```

Python 3.11.6

Comment: When you try to access `DatasetController.DatasetItemStructure`, the class `DatasetController` hasn't been defined yet. Is there a reason you need to use nested classes here?

Comment: there is no serious reason, I just would like to keep the logic that `DatasetItemStructure` and `DatasetInfoStructure` are part of `DatasetController`

Comment: @Gawain then just separate concerns if that is the only reason.

Comment: They're already grouped together in a module namespace. Nested classes have all kinds of weird scoping surprises in Python, so just avoid them unless you have a really good reason to use them.